# Header('last-modified') on godaddy host doesn't work?

Tags: php, header, host

I'm trying to generate a file(.css) and send it with PHP.
However, before I print the text, I set headers such

```
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($css));
header('Content-Type: text/css');
```

The issue is with the last-modified header which has been set

```
$lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime($file));
header('Last-Modified: '.$lastModified);
```

Now on my server (XAMPP), it works great, however, on GoDaddy hosting, it seems to ignore my last-modified header and always set it as the current time...

any help?

here you can see how it has been set and how is it on the host
[image]

Comment: You'd have to ask godaddy if they automatically inject any response headers, including that one, which might overwrite what you've set in PHP. I've known hosting companies do that (I mean inject response headers, not necessarily that specific one).

Comment: @ADyson why they would do that? BTW, when I remove the header set, that header won't even be sent.

Comment: `why they would do that`...that's a question you'd need to ask them not me, but some do it. Some of the free hosts even inject HTML content into the body of your pages as well (e.g. to show adverts).

Comment: `when I remove the header set, that header won't even be sent`...well that changes things a little bit, makes the injection theory less likely. What about if you set an arbitrary date hard-coded into the header, instead of reading it from the filesystem? Does it come out exactly as shown then?

Comment: @ADyson I solved it by doing a custom header with that value and it works, which means the value that I was trying to set is okay... anyway thanks for helping <3

Comment: Can you show us your exact setup used to make `style.css` get parsed by PHP in the first place?

Comment: `Accept-Ranges: bytes` - really - for a _stylesheet_? And are you then even _handling_ range requests correctly in your script?